# Event на удаление расширения chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookie, chrome-extension

Добрый день.

Существует ли в браузере Chrome какое-то событие, которое позволяет отследить удаление расширения для браузера(нужно удалить куки и прочую пользовательскую информацию)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При удалении расширения из Google Crome вы не получаете никаких событий,но есть полезный метод, благодаря чему вы можете удалить данные или выполнить другие действия. Когда пользователь удаляет ваше расширение, API перенаправляет пользователя на отдельную страницу где можно сделать дополнительные действия..:

> setUninstallURL

`chrome.runtime.setUninstallURL(string url, function callback)`

Данная возможность поможет вам, детально в [Документации](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-setUninstallURL)

Comment: Не понял, как эта функция поможет удалить куки?

Comment: @vihtor - эта функция не удаляет куки... а при удалении расширения перенаправляет пользователя на новую страницу где можно сделать любые действия )) вы открыли документацию ?

Comment: уточните пожалуйста, каким образом какая либо страница (на которую вы предлагаете перенаправить пользователя) сможет удалить куку, к которой она не имеет отношения?

Comment: Меня интересовала именно обработка удаления расширения. Очень хороший ответ, спасибо огромное!

Comment: @vihtor  Вы наверно не правильно поняли )) новая страница - это не страница где то.... открывается системная вкладка Google Chrome где подключается заранее подготовленный файл в расширении

Comment: Куку удалять буду через коллбэк и chrome.cookies.remove()

Comment: @Arsen, да, действительно я не так это понял. Но и в документации ничего не сказано про то, что можно указать файл из расширения. Но при этом явно сказано что схема *chrome-extension://EXTENSION_ID/* не разрешается. Видимо я всё ещё ничего не понял :(

Comment: @vihtor Лично у меня серверная часть расширения написана на node.js. Собственно туда я и буду перенаправлять пользователя через вышеназванную функцию. А вот внутри него куки и будут удаляться.

Answer (score 0):

Говорят что ничего подобно в Chrome Extension API нету, но есть вот [это](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-setUninstallURL). 
Обсуждение данной функции давным давно закончилось закрытием [issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=19383)